# Saving bulk data in a query - laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I have a input field for entering numbers into a database. Now, a unique token is created for each number that is entered.

Now currently with my code below, when i enter `+144223202320,+4403224202340`, it is saved into the database but both numbers are saved in the same column like

```
  phone                              token  
   +144223202320,+4403224202340    dfsfsfsdfsdfdsfs
```

But this is what i want

```
phone                              token  
+144223202320                1111112323242343
+4403224202340               dfsfsfsdfsdfdsfs
```

**Controller**

```
  public function send( Request $request)
      {
        do {
          //generate a random string using Laravel's str_random helper
          $token = str_random();
          }
         while (Invite::where('token', $token)->first());

         $invite = Invite::create([
            'phone' => $request->get('phone'),
            'token' => $token
        ]);

          return redirect()->back()->with('status','Message  successfully sent');

      }
```

How can i get this done please?

Comment: explode `$request->get('phone')` using the comma and loop for each match

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Explode the phone number and write a record in the database for each phone you get

```
public function send( Request $request)
{
     foreach(explode(",", $request->get('phone')) as $phone){
          do {
               //generate a random string using Laravel's str_random helper
               $token = str_random();
          }while (Invite::where('token', $token)->first());

          $invite = Invite::create([
               'phone' => $phone,
               'token' => $token
          ]);
     }

     return redirect()->back()->with('status','Message  successfully sent');

}
```

**Update**

Seems like in a for loop the object is not being recreated. Use this approach instead

```
public function send( Request $request)
{
     foreach(explode(",", $request->get('phone')) as $phone){
          do {
               //generate a random string using Laravel's str_random helper
               $token = str_random();
          }while (Invite::where('token', $token)->first());

          $invite = new Invite;
          $invite->phone = $phone;
          $invite->token = $token;
          $invite->save();
     }

     return redirect()->back()->with('status','Message  successfully sent');

}
```

Comment: It is just saving the first number

Answer (score 0):

You can try this approach with recursive check of tokens.
P.S. You might need to make few adjustments to work 100% on your code.

```
public function send(Request $request){
    $phones = explode("," $request->phone);
    foreach($phones as $phone){
        $token = $this->generateUniqueInviteToken();
        if($token){
            $invite = new Invite();
            $invite->phone = $phone;
            $invite->token = $token;
            if($invite->save()){
                return redirect()->back()->with('status', 'Message  successfully sent');
            }
            return redirect()->back()->with('status', 'FAILED');
        }
    }
}

public function generateUniqueInviteToken(){
    $token = str_random();
    $checkedInvite = Invite::where("token", $token)->first();

    if(!$checkedInvite){
        return $token;
    }else{
        $this->generateUniqueInviteToken();
    }
}
```